# HTML does not respond to the stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I don't know why my html does not respond to my stylsheet. Please help!
Both html and stylesheet are in same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>First try</title> 
<link type=“text/css” rel=“stylesheet” href=“stylesheet.css”/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My first html </h1>
<p>I wish it works!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your quotes - at least in this example - are not actual quotes. Also, is your stylesheet in the same folder as your page?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: First thing I'd check are the fancy quotes I see like in `type=“text/css”` etc.

Comment: Don't "code" on Word...

Comment: If you really need to code, use a plain text editor with support for UTF-8 encoding. In Windows, probably **Notepad++** (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is your initial best-and-free shot. In macOS, **TextWrangler** from the App Store is something similar. For GNU/Linux... erhm... basically everything, probably **Gedit** or equivalent.

Comment: Thank you guys!
I use TextEdit in mac. Somehow I can only type out fancy ".

Comment: [*You're welcome...*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41489908/1415724) @EvaTannenbaum ;-)

Comment: @EvaTannenbaum — TextEdit is a word processor, not a text editor. Use a text editor instead. Sublime Text and Atom are good choices.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, it's because of all your curly quotes `“ ”`.

Change them to regular quotes `"`.

And don't use Word to code with (or similar processing software), use a code editor.

**Edit:**

So, as a (free) service to you; copy/paste this exactly as shown:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First try</title> 
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My first html</h1>
        <p>Now it works!</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS: (stylesheet.css)

```
body {

    font-family: Georgia;

}
```

Comment: I posted this since I  feel rep should not come of this.